# 2-way Repeated-Measure ANOVA on a sample made of sub-sample

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, repeated-measures, statistical-power

We are conducting an experiment were we asked people to perform the same task several time, with 2 type of tools and in 5 different conditions. Each time, we measure the performance on the task. To analyse if there is any effects on the performance, we perform a 2-way Repeated-measure ANOVA where the 2 factors are thus the tool and the condition.

But we could not include lot of people because it is expensive and it takes time. So, to have a sufficiently large sample, we asked each people to perform the task several time instead of one time for each tool/conditions. The sample to analyse is thus composed of `N=N_people*N_repetition` were we decided to increase `N_repetition` instead of `N_people` (`N_repetition > 1` instead of `N_repetition = 1` ; we kept `N_people = 15`).

So, even though we know that there is a performance variability intra and inter subject, this approach did not disturbed me at first, because our goal is to analyse the effect of tool/condition on the whole population of performances (Which is thus a population made of subpopulations from each people). But is it really a good idea or we should have asked people to perform the task only one time per tool/condition and increase the number of people ?